# how to use custom JSON schema in function javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am having the custom schema in Javascript. 
I have to write the function for that when i will call web service thae data will come as the schema we have or not, we have to make validation in the web service function.
Can you please tell me how to create the validation or function for particular json schema.

```
const loginSchema = {
  body: {
    type: 'object',
    data: {
      type: 'object',
      required: ['application'],
      properties: {
        application: { type: 'string' },
      },
    },
    notification: {
      type: 'object',
      required: ['title', 'body'],
      properties: {
        title: { type: 'string' },
        body: { type: 'string' },
      },
    },
    token: {
      type: 'array',
      required: ['application'],
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: https://ajv.js.org/ maybe?

Comment: i dont want to use other validator, i want to use my own validator? how to write that please help me?

Comment: Seems like too big of a question to ask here. If you don't want to use an existing validator, look at their source code and take inspiration from that.

Comment: if i have to use this schema in webservice calling function then what we have to do?

Comment: If you want to write your own validator then you have potentially months of work ahead of you. You would need to read the rfc documents and understand the official test suite. People use existing libraries to do this for a reason.